# Retrieving active directory data, filtering by specific group name

Tags: python, powershell, active-directory

I'm performing the following powershell script to retrieve all the groups that the users belong to, now what i want is to change it a bit and see all the users that belong to 3 specific groups(it doesn't matter if they belong to more than one group).

I'm trying to retrieve that data through this script but it is not working for me:

```
$UsersPerGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=ITE,OU=HQ,DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} |Sort-Object UserName | Select UserName, Groups
```

If I run this script I get the following error, repeated many times:

```
Get-ADGroup : Error parsing query: 'employeeportaldl' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.
At line:5 char:25
+ Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup -Filter employeeportaldl | Select ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

Screenshot:

[image]

also I would like to know if my script itself is correct, then I also need to export it as a .csv or .txt file to be read by a program I'm building on python, so if possible which would be the best format to be exported to, so that it can be easily scanned or read from my python program.

Thank you!

Comment: Where error are you getting? I just did a test in my environment using your syntax and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm gonna add sceebshots

Comment: Please, no screenshots, just paste in the filter expression that you're having problems with.

Comment: That is an error for something you are not showing in your script. I think I removed it during my test as I was testing. Oops. I apologize. Edited your filter back in.

Comment: `-Filter` searches AD, piping group names into `Get-AdGroup` gets specific groups by Identity. It doesn't make sense to use both together. They are in different ParameterSets, so you can't use both, and that's the error you see. I would answer fully, but your script is so different from what you ask for; that I don't believe what you ask for is what you actually want. "*I just want to see all the users that belong to 3 specific groups*" would be `$group1name, $group2name, $group3name | Get-AdGroupMember`, your code is .. "*users in an OU, and which of 3 groups each user is a member of*" ?

Comment: so, i just wanna see specific groups and the users that are contained in those  groups, the script above is my attempt to retrieve that data, so i need to modify the script, but it is not working for me